# wp_editor() youtube link does not load video

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, editor, wp-editor

Hello I am trying to get a preview of the youtube video when pasted to the editor but it keeps loading plain instead of loading the video preview.

I have created an options page in admin side for a userrole. Then I have used `wp_editor();` on that options page.

also enqeued `wp_enqueue_media();`
& `wp_enqueue_script( 'mce-view' );`

Please help

[image]

I am expecting something like this.
[image]

Comment: Instead of pasting in the `<iframe>...</iframe>`, just paste the video's URL into the visual editor. WordPress's [oEmbed](https://wordpress.org/support/article/embeds/) system will recognize it and should display the video preview.

Comment: @PatJ that's not the actual case. It will just show an url